# In SAP SQ01, how can I avoid an ABAP runtime error due to a returned null value in a local calculated field?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-query

I've created an `SQ01` query with the intention of returning order schedule lines that have an open quantity based off of the Delivered Quantity (`MENGE` - `GLMNG`), this has been configured in a local calculated field. SAP ERP calculates this field in Table `MEPO1320`, field name `OBMNG`, and can be seen in the Delivery Schedule tab in `ME23N`, however `OBMNG` calculates open quantity from the GR quantity, which doesn't meet the requirements of what this query is intended for.

I have named my calculated field `ZOBMNG`, I am using this field as one of the selection criteria, returning all values not equal to 0 (all open schedule lines).

My issue is, if there is no quantity delivered, SAP ERP leaves the `GLMNG` field as a null value, and I am finding it difficult with the basic logic available within the 'complex calculation' area to avoid a runtime error.

It is important to note that I need to know where there is a null value, as the null value represents a 0 delivered quantity.

I broke it down into two steps, the first looks if the delivered quantity is greater than 0, if so, subtract `GLMNG` (delivered quantity) from `MENGE` (schedule quantity):

- Condition: `GLMNG > 0`
- Formula: `MENGE - GLMNG`

I have run this independently and it does return partially delivered schedule lines. I haven't been successful through various methods to return 0 otherwise.

What I've tried, all have ended up as runtime errors:

1. Condition: `GLMNG = 0`

   Formula: `MENGE` (Looking to just return the schedule line qty if there is 0 delivered)

   No second condition or formula, just `MENGE` in the otherwise section
2. Multiplying & dividing `GLMNG` by 0 & 1 and using DIV/MOD both together and separately - all to try return 0.
3. Creating a second calculated field to define `GLMNG` as a text or numerical value of 0 and calling up this second calculated field in the first calculated field.

Is it possible to achieve what I need? Please also note I am not authorised to write code within the applicable section in `SQ02`.

Comment: Too many buzz words. Give us the code finally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's achievable with this logic to avoid a runtime error unless you can edit the code in SQ02.

> ```
> Please also note I am not authorised to write code within the applicable section in SQ02.
> ```

This is a problem.